# Compile and Run java program in linux with path to the .java file and path to external jars

Tags: java, linux, jar, javac, javacompiler

Yesterday I solved a problem with an answer here on stackoverflow. But I ended up with another problem, I will try to be clear:

I have a project folder in the `/home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/` directory where inside of it is the java file `"xlsToCsv.java"` and another directory with the external jars that I need in `/home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/jars`.

Now I need to compile and run my program. Yesterday I ran a command that assumed that I was already inside of `/home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/`, and the commands were:

```
javac -cp ".:./jars/*" xlsToCsv.java

java -cp ".:./jars/*" xlsToCsv
```

The problem was solved and I was able to run my program without any problems. But, my program was supposed to run from the root directory, ie, the directory where it is when I open the linux terminal without the need to make a "cd" command.

So, when I open the terminal the path to the .java file is:

```
/home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/
```

And the path to jars folder is:

/home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/jars/*

Can someone explain to me what I have to do, and the reason so? Because more that run the program, I want to know the reasons and understand the classpath mechanism in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using relative classpath. and instread of "./jars/*" use the absolute path "/home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/jars/*"

**EDIT:**

```
javac -cp "/home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/jars/*" /home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/xlsToCsv.java

java -cp "/home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/:/home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/jars/*" xlsToCsv
```

Comment: So, for you, what has to be the full commands? For compile and run. Understanding that the path to the file is at /home/demo/Desktop/xlsToCsv/xlsToCsv.java

Comment: It's working now, I will put in two comments the command that I used to compile and run the file.

Comment: **Compile -->**  javac -cp "/home/demo/Desktop/xls_to_csv/jars/*" /home/demo/Desktop/xls_to_csv/xlsToCsv.java

Comment: **Run -->** java -cp "/home/demo/Desktop/xls_to_csv/:/home/demo/Desktop/xls_to_csv/jars/*" xlsToCsv

Comment: yes I forgot to include the classpath for the directory

Comment: Thank you. While I tried your option I read an article about classpath in java, may be it will be usefull to someone in the future: http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html