# Compile Java class files with external multiple jars using Javac

Tags: java, jar, .class-file

`.java` files are present in this folder `exposeservices` .

I am trying to convert these `.java` files to `.class` files using the below command.

These `.java` files have import statements so I have downloaded the jars as external dependency and supplying the path to java via the `classpath` command.These external dependent jars are present in the `/Users/Desktop/jarscheck/` folder.

**What am I actually trying to do ?**

I had some WSDL files which I am trying to package it into a jar file using `wsimport`, since this is deprecated above Java 9 I guess, I have parsed the WSDL file and now want to convert those to .class file so that I can create a JAR file

**Enviornment: JDK 17**

**Which path am I executing the below command ?**

```
cd "/Users/Desktop/workspace/GitHub/jar generation/api-config-elements/exposeservices"
```

---

command

```
javac -classpath ".:/Users/Desktop/jarscheck/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar" -sourcepath  "/Users/Desktop/workspace/GitHub/jar generation/api-config-elements/exposeservices" *.java
```

Error that I am getting is,

```
ApiConfig.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiConfig.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiConfig.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
                                  ^
ApiConfig.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiElements.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiElements.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiElements.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiElements.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
                                  ^
ApiElements.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiElements.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

External dependent jars

[image]

**Steps I have tried before,**

I have referred to this,

[Compiling Java files with the dependent jars using windows Cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321023/compiling-java-files-with-the-dependent-jars-using-windows-cmd)

Result: I got the same errors above.

2.I also referred to this,
[Compile and run java program with mutiple external jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314602/compile-and-run-java-program-with-mutiple-external-jar-files)

I still got the same errors.

Edited:
After trying out the suggestion from the comments these are the errors,

```
ApiPaymentGateway.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGateway.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGateway.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGateway.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGateway.java:9: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGateway.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiPaymentGateway.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiPaymentGateway.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlRootElement(name = "ApiPaymentGateway", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
^
  symbol: class XmlRootElement
ApiPaymentGateway.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    protected JAXBElement<ApiOrders> aApiOrders;
              ^
  symbol:   class JAXBElement
  location: class ApiPaymentGateway
ApiOrders.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiOrders.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiOrders.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiOrders.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiOrders.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiOrders.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ApiOrders", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiPaymentGateway.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    public JAXBElement<ApiOrders> getAApiOrders() {
           ^
  symbol:   class JAXBElement
  location: class ApiPaymentGateway
ApiPaymentGateway.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setAApiOrders(JAXBElement<ApiOrders> value) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class JAXBElement
  location: class ApiPaymentGateway
ApiShipping.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiShipping.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiShipping.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiShipping.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
                                  ^
ApiShipping.java:9: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiShipping.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiShipping.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ApiShipping", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
                       ^
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:9: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlRootElement(name = "ApiPaymentGatewayResponse", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
^
  symbol: class XmlRootElement
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    protected JAXBElement<ApiTracking> ApiPaymentGatewayResult;
              ^
  symbol:   class JAXBElement
  location: class ApiPaymentGatewayResponse
ApiTracking.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiTracking.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiTracking.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiTracking.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
                                  ^
ApiTracking.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiTypeInfo.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiTypeInfo.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiTypeInfo.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiTypeInfo.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
                                  ^
ApiTypeInfo.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiTypeInfo.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiTypeInfo.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ApiTypeInfo", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiTypeInfo.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlSeeAlso({
^
  symbol: class XmlSeeAlso
ApiTracking.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiTracking.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ApiTracking", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiTracking.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlSeeAlso({
^
  symbol: class XmlSeeAlso
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    public JAXBElement<ApiTracking> getApiPaymentGatewayResult() {
           ^
  symbol:   class JAXBElement
  location: class ApiPaymentGatewayResponse
ApiPaymentGatewayResponse.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setApiPaymentGatewayResult(JAXBElement<ApiTracking> value) {
                                            ^
  symbol:   class JAXBElement
  location: class ApiPaymentGatewayResponse
ApiStockHouse.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiStockHouse.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiStockHouse.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiStockHouse.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiStockHouse.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ApiStockHouse", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ArrayOfErrorMessage.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ArrayOfErrorMessage.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ArrayOfErrorMessage.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ArrayOfErrorMessage.java:9: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ArrayOfErrorMessage.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ArrayOfErrorMessage.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfErrorMessage", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ErrorMessage.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ErrorMessage.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ErrorMessage.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ErrorMessage.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ErrorMessage.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ErrorMessage.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ErrorMessage", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiWarehouse.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
                                  ^
ApiWarehouse.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlSeeAlso({
^
  symbol: class XmlSeeAlso
ApiLandingPage.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiLandingPage.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiLandingPage.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiLandingPage.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiLandingPage.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ApiLandingPage", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiBatchJobs.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiBatchJobs.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiBatchJobs.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiBatchJobs.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiBatchJobs.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiBatchJobs.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ApiBatchJobs", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiInventory.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiInventory.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiInventory.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiInventory.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
                                  ^
ApiInventory.java:9: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiInventory.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiInventory.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ApiInventory", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiCacheInfo.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiCacheInfo.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiCacheInfo.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiCacheInfo.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
ApiCacheInfo.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
^
  symbol: class XmlAccessorType
ApiCacheInfo.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
@XmlType(name = "ApiCacheInfo", propOrder = {
^
  symbol: class XmlType
ApiCurrency.java:5: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
                                  ^
ApiCurrency.java:6: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
                                  ^
ApiCurrency.java:7: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
                                  ^
ApiCurrency.java:8: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
                                  ^
100 errors
only showing the first 100 errors, of 1921 total; use -Xmaxerrs if you would like to see more
```

EDIT 2

[image]

Comment: Have a go with this: `javac -classpath '.:/Users/Desktop/jarscheck/*' -sourcepath  "/Users/Desktop/workspace/GitHub/jar generation/api-config-elements/exposeservices" *.java` (with the proviso that the source path is *one* path containing the directory called 'jar generation')

Comment: @g00se sourcepath contains the `.java` files which have the above imports and these are the files that I need to convert them to `.class` files.

Comment: Yes, I know. Did it work?

Comment: @g00se Nope I am still getting errors

Comment: Please post the latest errors

Comment: It will be a lot easier to build your project when you use a build tool such as [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) instead of trying to do this manually by directly calling `javac`.

Comment: @g00se Posted them.

Comment: All those missing classes are present in [jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.1/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.1.jar) Your jars probably missed them

Comment: @g00se What would be the solution then ? should I change or add options or change syntax of the external libraries ?

Comment: You need to add the jar with the missing classes

Comment: @g00se - For these errors `package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist` the jar is added right so why does it show again ?

Comment: *the jar is added right* What do you mean by that? What did you change?

Comment: @g00se The jars are present in the `-classpath ` already also please have a look at the above screenshot. So what is missing is what I am trying to understand ?

Comment: So you tell me *which jar you have on your classpath* contains `jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType`?

Comment: @g00se `jakarta-annotation-api-1.3.5 jar` from the above screenshot

Comment: You're wrong. It doesn't

Comment: @g00se - Sorry is it `jakarta-xml-bind` as I can see the package here of the class  https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/xml/bind/annotation/xmlaccesstype ?

Comment: Remind me: what OS are you using?

Comment: @g00se Mac OS Ventura and terminal is ZSH

Comment: `jar tf jakarta-xml-bind.jar | grep 'jakarta/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType' || echo Not present`

Comment: @g00se Please the screenshot under **Edit 2** I downloaded this jar `implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.3'` from Maven repository. Is it still not under here ?

Comment: You don't seem to be paying much attention to my comments. Firstly, what was the result of the command I asked you to run?

Comment: @g00se It said "Not Present" I then understood and downloaded the jars that you see in the new screenshot

Comment: But I've already posted a link to the jar containing the missing classes and I can see one with that name is not in your list ...

Comment: @g00se it worked finally now how did you find the exact package name ? I too searched in Google but couldn't find it ?

Comment: It seems so long ago now I can't even remember ;) It involved Google and looking on the Maven site

Comment: @g00se - Please add an answer I will accept it so that it can help someone else also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those missing classes are present in [jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.1/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.1.jar). The `-classpath` argument in your original `javac` command line did not include this JAR file, and you must have missed it in subsequent updates as well.

To fix, change the `-classpath` argument to use a wildcard and include all the JARs in the `jarscheck` directory in your classpath:

```
javac -classpath ".:/Users/Desktop/jarscheck/*" -sourcepath  "/Users/Desktop/workspace/GitHub/jar generation/api-config-elements/exposeservices" *.java
```